# How to find out uptime in minutes?

Tags: bash, shell, solaris

How to find out and save to file uptime on Solaris in minutes without cutting and converting it ? Is there any elegant way of doing it? Thanks for answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a reliable and accurate way to get the number of minutes since last boot on Solaris:

```
kstat -n system_misc | 
    nawk '/boot_time/ {printf("%d minutes\n",(srand()-$2)/60)}'
```

Under `nawk`, the `srand()` function returns the number of seconds since the epoch while the `boot_time` `kstat` statistic returns the number of seconds since the epoch at boot time. Subtracting the former from the latter gives the number of seconds, and dividing it further by 60 gives the number of minutes since last boot.

Answer (score 3):

On Solaris, the `uptime(1)` command is just a link to `w(1)`.  You can find its source code at https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/master/usr/src/cmd/w/w.c.

There, you will find that `uptime(1)` gets the boot time as recorded in `/var/run/utmpx`.  Just as they do, you can read the data from this file using the `getutxent(3)` family of functions, and look for a record with `ut_type == BOOT_TIME`.  In this record, look at the `ut_tv` field, which is a `struct timeval` and contains the seconds and microseconds of the boot time.  From this you can calculate how long the system has been up.

(Edit: I just noticed the [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) tag.  This solution would be more suitable for calling from a C program.  Oh well, maybe it will be useful to someone.)

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure that this will work on Solaris but...

```
uptime | awk -F ',' ' {print $1} ' | awk ' {print $3} ' | awk -F ':' ' {hrs=$1; min=$2; print hrs*60 + min} '
```

Comment: Oh bummer, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

A small improvement on @jilliagre's suggestion is to use kstat(1m) to extract more information for you before passing to nawk(1):

```
$ kstat -p -n system_misc -s boot_time| nawk '{printf("%d minutes\n",(srand()-$2)/60)}'
26085 minutes
```

`-p` means "parseable output", `-s` selects the specific stat underneath `-n` module name.